# openvidu connecting from an external network, only the video is not output

Tags: rtsp, coturn, redis-server, openvidu, kurento-media-server

using openvidu 2.9.0

It seems like you have OpenVidu installed on a Hyper-V virtual machine with a public IP, and port forwarding is set up. However, when someone connects to the video conference from an external IP, their video doesn’t show up. Session connection appears to be established properly, chat works, and participant information is displayed correctly, except the issue with the remote participant’s video not appearing

All tests on the internal network were successful.